# How to set two runing internet connections at same time?

Tags: internet, connection

As the title say, I can't find the option how to set two internet connections running at same time. The problem is, when I want to watch IPTV (ethernet connection) and browsing on the internet (wlan connection) at the same time.

Is there any option to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [To allocate data usage efficiently with two internet connections](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63109/to-allocate-data-usage-efficiently-with-two-internet-connections/64344#64344). You want to set up a route to your IPTV IP addresses via the wired connection.